# Inserting new rows to a local database in c# using SqlCeDataAdapter

Tags: c#, database

I have a local SQL Server CE database (`mainDB.sdf`) with only one table called `Users`.

It consists of 7 columns:

- `Name (ntext)`
- `Surname (ntext)`
- `Nickname (nchar, unique, primary key)`
- `Gender (ntext)`
- `Status (ntext)`
- `City (ntext)`
- `Photo (image)`

I use objects:

```
private SqlCeConnection connection;
private SqlCeDataAdapter adapter;
private SqlCeCommandBuilder builder;
private DataSet data;
```

Firstly, I connect to a database:

```
connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = mainDB.sdf");
connection.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users";
adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
builder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder();
builder.DataAdapter = adapter;
data = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(data);
```

I try to insert a new row:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
byte[] im = ms.ToArray();
DataRow newRow = data.Tables[0].NewRow();
newRow["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
newRow["Surname"] = textBox2.Text;
newRow["Nickname"] = textBox3.Text;
newRow["Gender"] = listBox1.Text.Length > 0 ? listBox1.Text : null;
newRow["Status"] = radioButton1.Checked ? "Student" : radioButton2.Checked ? "Professional" : null;
newRow["City"] = comboBox1.Text.Length > 0 ? comboBox1.Text : null;
newRow["Photo"] = im;
data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);
adapter.Update(data);
connection.Close();
```

After this, I go to the table Users and there is no new data.
I think that SqlCeCommandBuilder should generate required commands. What am I missing here?

**IMPORTANT EDIT**:
Everything is working fine. It seems that c# creates two links to databases. The first one is in project folder called `mainDB.sdf` and it is empty. But there is another one in `bin\Debug` folder. As an absolute newbie I didn't know that. I could get all previous rows in that DB `mainDB.sdf1` choosing `New Query` and entering `SELECT * FROM USERS`. The same command with the first `mainDB.sdf` gives nothing. This was the issue.

Comment: Use appropriate data types for your columns. nText is for very large text, it's not for names (that are hardly ever longer then 10 characters).

Answer (score 1):

**Use `SqlCeCommand`**

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = mainDB.sdf");
connection.Open();

using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Users (Name, Surname, Nickname, Gender, Status, City, Photo) Values(@name,@surname,@nickname,@gender,@status,@city,@photo)", connection))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", textBox2.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname", textBox3.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", listBox1.Text.Length > 0 ? listBox1.Text : null);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", radioButton1.Checked ? "Student" : radioButton2.Checked ? "Professional" : null);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", comboBox1.Text.Length > 0 ? comboBox1.Text : null);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", im);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

connection.Close();
```

Comment: I tried to replace that part of my code: [DataRow...adapter.Update(data);] with your code. In fact, I have two problems. Firstly, I get "ArgumentNullException" with parameter "@gender", because "NULL" is allowed for that field. Secondly, if all the fields are supplied, I can not see any changes in my database after running my program. What can I try to do?

Comment: You can also try to specify the parameters this way: `com.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NText, 100){ Value=textBox1.Text });`

Comment: If your connection is alive and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't throw any Exception then you should see the new record in your SqlCe database! `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an `int` that is the number of rows affected. Check that too.

Comment: After changing the specification of parameters my program still forces to enter all fields though it shouldn't. "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" returns 1 but I can not see results. I connect mainDB.sdf and use "Show table data" on "Users" in "Server Explorer". There is only one line with all NULL's.

Comment: you can check which row was last inserted into the database: `var rowId = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection).ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: is this works at all? `new SqlCeCommand("SELECT INTO Users (Name, Surname, Nickname, Gender, Status, City, Photo) Values('Josef','John','jozi','male','married','nyc',null)", connection).ExecuteNonQuery();` inserting some dummy record directly from code?

Comment: rowId is {}. I have changed "SELECT" to "INSERT". The command doesn't throw any exceptions, but there are no new rows in the database.

Comment: Yeah, it's INSERT, sorry. It's weird. What is the datatype of `Photo`? Because there is no `image` data type in Sql Compact Edition. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174642%28v=sql.90%29.aspx Can you ignore/delete the Image column?